# How to put a floating widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter

What I want to do is make a TextField stay in the same position by scrolling down the screen. I want to know if there is a way to do this?

This is the TextField that I want to be floating:

[image]

This is the code, the `CardWidget` are just cards and searchInput is the textField:

```
class RouteListPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _RouteListPageState createState() => _RouteListPageState();
}

class _RouteListPageState extends State<RouteListPage> {

  TextEditingController searchController = new TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            searchInput(),
            CardWidget(),
            CardWidget(),
            CardWidget(),
            CardWidget(),
            SizedBox(height: 25.0)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget searchInput(){
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24, vertical: 25.0),
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Color(0xfff6f6f6),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
        boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.black45,
            offset: Offset(0.0, 2.0),
            blurRadius: 10.0,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: TextField(
              controller: searchController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Buscar rutas",
                hintStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: "WorkSansSemiBold", fontSize: 16.0),
                border: InputBorder.none
              ),
            )
          ),
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {},
            child: Container(
              child: Icon(Icons.search, color: Tema.Colors.loginGradientEnd, size: 28.0)
            )
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: You should use a `Stack`: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html

Comment: With the stack the TextField is hidden when I scroll in the screen, I want is for it to float like a FAB

Comment: Can you provide a code sample.

Comment: I already put the code sample, thank you very much!

Comment: Why not just bring your input outside of the SingleChildScrollView, so only the Column will be scrollable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a `Stack` widget and have the scrolling widget below the `TextField` widget. Use the `Positioned` widget to control the position of `searchInput()`

Your `build` method will change to this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                CardWidget(),
                CardWidget(),
                CardWidget(),
                CardWidget(),
                SizedBox(height: 25.0)
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 24.0,
            left: 0.0,
            right: 0.0,
            child: searchInput(),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of **SingleChildScrollView** try using this

```
Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      searchInput(),
      ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          CardWidget(),
          CardWidget(),
          CardWidget()
        ],
      )
    ],
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Stack` and add your scrollview and the input as children:

```
Stack(
  children: [
    SingleChildScrollView(),
    searchInput(),
  ],
)
```